# Data not being inserted to Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

HI I am trying to insert data into a database hosted on Azure. I getting an exemption error. I tested the code below on a local database and it works fine. Is there some additional code I need for Azure?

```
        protected void Submit_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn;
        SqlCommand comm;
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        comm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Site (SiteName, SiteEmail) VALUES (@SiteName, @SiteEmail)", conn);
        comm.Parameters.Add("@SiteName", System.Data.SqlDbType.Text);
        comm.Parameters["@SiteName"].Value = "Whatever Time, Place";
        comm.Parameters.Add("@SiteEmail", System.Data.SqlDbType.Text);
        comm.Parameters["@SiteEmail"].Value = "Dan@whatevertimeplace.com";
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            label1.Text = "It worked";
        }
        catch
        {
            label1.Text = "Error submitting the form!";

        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't done so already, you need to configure your Azure SQL Server to allow connections from your client.

This can be done from within the Azure portal by navigating to the sql server configure tab and adding your client's ip address to the list of allowed ip addresses:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the replies. I rewrote my catch to give more detail to the exemption. It was a clustered index error.

Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again.

For some reason, all of the tables had a clustered index except one.